# What conditions make the ring of Laurent polynomials in non-commuting variables countable?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

Suppose we have some commutative ring $R$ and the ring of Laurent polynomials in a finite number of non-commuting variables $S=R\langle x_1,\,x_1^{-1},\ldots,\,x_n,\,x_n^{-1}\rangle$. Under what conditions on $R$ can we say $S$ is countable? Quite clearly this is the case when $R$ is countable, but under what conditions does this hold?

Answer (score 1):

This is the case precisely when $R$ is itself countable (this follows by completely standard cardinality arguments).

Comment: Sorry, I just realised how ambiguous that question was. I was wondering upon which conditions we could make R countable

Comment: @SamWilliams $S$ is countable if and only if $R$ is countable (that is what I meant by "precisely").

Comment: No I understand that. What I mean is, are there any conditions on a commutative ring for it to be countable?

Comment: @SamWilliams You mean ring-theoretical conditions?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. Sorry, I was so involved in the question that I am dealing with I didn't think to remove all the faff and just ask main problem.

Comment: @SamWilliams That becomes rather vague then, so I really have no idea what sort of thing you are looking for.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25189/discussion-between-sam-williams-and-tobias-kildetoft).